AppBar color stays changed after scrolling and moving to different tab
When I scroll down in homepage the appbar color darkens but when i click any other tab the color stays same. I want the color to be the default appbar color when changed to new tab. 
When not scrolled 
When scrolled
When changed to another tab
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

int currentIndex = 0;

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('flutter app'),
        ),
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: currentIndex,
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return const Placeholder(
                  fallbackHeight: 200,
                );
              },
            ),
            const Center(child: Text('search')),
            const Center(child: Text('user')),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          selectedIndex: currentIndex,
          destinations: const [
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'search'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'user'),
          ],
          onDestinationSelected: (index) {
            setState(
              () {
                currentIndex = index;
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

tried:
scrolledUnderElevation: 0 and surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent
but it still remains a little dark. 
This is what it should look like

weird, But you can definitely try to force transparency in the AppBar:
forceMaterialTransparency: true,  


thanks, that sort of works, but is there any better solution? now it completely stays the same whether i scroll or not

@ShojolAhmed , for your desired design (transparent appbar) you should explicitly set its color to Colors.transparent , scrollUnderElevation to 0 and the attribute in this answer also, to guarantee the output.

you can get ride of this using backgroundColor and surfaceTintColor like this:
 AppBar(
          title: const Text('flutter app'),
          surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),

or you can change forceMaterialTransparency to true as answered by A-E like this:
 AppBar(
          title: const Text('flutter app'),
          forceMaterialTransparency: true,
        ),


Forces the AppBar's Material widget type to be MaterialType.transparency (instead of Material's default type).
This will remove the visual display of backgroundColor and elevation, and affect other characteristics of the AppBar's Material widget.

read-more
